# What is wrong with this code? (Drupal)

Tags: php, drupal-7

I use this code in my subtheme page--front.tpl file, but I can not see any message on my front page like my code bellow.

```
  <?php

  $flag = drupal_is_front_page();

  if ($flag) {

    drupal_set_message("Welcome to front page of this site.");

  }
  else
  {
     drupal_set_message("Now you are in page other than front page.");
  }

?>
```

Comment: Does the other message appear when you are NOT on the front page?

Comment: @Borniet No, Its not working...

Comment: hi is drupal executing page--front.tpl file just type some thing like echo "In front page"; die; if drupal is executing page--front.tpl file then issue becomes simpler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/7

https://drupal.org/node/39891

Try the `$is_front` expression:

```
 <?php
 if($is_front)
 {
    echo "you are on the front page";
 }
 else
 {
    echo "you are not on the front page";
 }
```

Comment: Have you cleared your cache after you make the change to your template? Are you sure Drupal is picking up the template?

Answer (score 0):

Try this format for setting the message:

```
drupal_set_message(t("Welcome to front page of this site."));
```

Answer (score 0):

**page--front.tpl.php is always front page**! So you don't need the if statement!

And if you are on another page it uses *page.tpl.php*! You should use this code in page.tpl.php.

Answer (score 0):

The message will be queued for the next page and will not be displayed on the current page  since drupal_set_message is called on the theme level and by then the message variable has already been rendered.

So if you visit the front page, and then go to another page, the message "Welcome to front page of this site." will be displayed on the other page.